# How do I paste in specific cells with openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to select a range of cells from an origin excel into a destination excel. With the code below I manage to do that (I need to extract the data out of E6:E15). The data however is pasted into the cells E6:E15 in the destination workbook as well.

How do I past into different cells? For example F6:F15?

Code:

```
import openpyxl

wbo = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'file_origin.xlsx', read_only=True)
wbd = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'file_destination.xlsx')

wso= wb['Sheet1']
wsd= wb1['Sheet1']

for row in wso['E6':'E15']:
    for cell in row:
        wsd[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl

wbo = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'file_origin.xlsx', read_only=True)
wbd = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'file_destination.xlsx')

#attach the ranges to the workbooks
wso= wbo['Sheet1']['E6':'E15']
wsd= wbd['Sheet1']['F6':'F15']

#step1 : pair the rows
#since it is the same number of rows 
#row 6 will pair with 6, 7 with 7  ,....
for row1,row2 in zip(wso,wsd):
    #within the row pair, pair the cells
    for cell1, cell2 in zip(row1,row2):
        #assign the value of cell 1 to the destination cell 2 for each row
        cell2.value = cell1.value
#save document
wbd.save('destination.xlsx')
```